# Get upcoming Stripe invoice for prorated change in quantity

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to get the cost of changing the quantity of a subscription using Stripe. I found the [Upcoming](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/upcoming?lang=php) API, which looks like it should work, but I've not been able to work out the right combination of arguments to pass to it.

This returns the error `You must pass one of plan, price, or price_data.`:

```
$this->stripe->invoices->upcoming([
    'customer' => $this->stripe_id,
    'subscription' => $this->subscription_id,
    'subscription_items' => [[
      'quantity' => $quantity
    ]]
 ]
```

But when I add the price id, as below, I get the error `Cannot add multiple subscription items with the same plan: price_1H...`

```
$this->stripe->invoices->upcoming([
    'customer' => $this->stripe_id,
    'subscription' => $this->subscription_id,
    'subscription_items' => [[
        'price' => $this->price_id,
        'quantity' => $quantity
    ]]
]));
```

Removing the subscription id then only returns the cost of a brand new subscription, not the prorated invoice for the existing one.

Answer (score 5):

As always, two seconds after posting the question I worked it out - as well as passing the subscription id, the subscription item's id needs to be passed as well, which I did by this snippet:

```
$subscription = $this->stripe->subscriptions->retrieve($this->subscription_id);
$this->stripe->invoices->upcoming([
    'customer' => $this->stripe_id,
    'subscription' => $this->subscription_id,
    'subscription_items' => [[
        'id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->id,
        'quantity' => $quantity
    ]]
]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to tell you: the `subscription_item` need the existing item `id` or it is treated as a new (additional) item.